# Why do I keep getting error 'Double' has no member 'text'?

Tags: swift

I'm getting data from the OpenWeatherMap API.

Why do I keep getting the error:

> Value of type 'Double' has no member 'text'

for only the `humidity.text` line?

```
let humidity = (self.document?.main?.humidity!)!
let tempeMax = (self.document?.main?.temp_max!)! - 273.15
let tempeMin = (self.document?.main?.temp_min!)! - 273.15
humidity.text = humidity.text! + "  " + String(format:"%.0f", humidity)
temp.text = temp.text! + "  " + String(format:"%.0f", tempe)
```

Comment: Because apparently `humidity` is a `Double`. BTW all those exclamation points are making my eyes burn - no offense. I suggest you go read up on Optionals in Swift.

Comment: Yes but tempMax and Min are also doubles

Comment: Do you have a humidity label you are trying to update? You need to reference the label, not the local `humidity` variable of type `Double`.

Comment: You aren't trying to access the (non-existent) `text` property of either `tempeMax` or `tempeMin`.

Comment: Unrelated but you can avoid the *kelvin-dance* if you add the parameter `units=metric`

Comment: 1) use `guard / if let` to remove all that force unwrapping. 2) use different names for your local variables and IBOutlets (i.e. `humidity`) 3) It looks like you're appending the string representation of a humidity value to a text label. Much better to have these as 2 separate labels (put them in a horizontal `UIStackView` for spacing if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `humidity` variable is a `Double`, and has no `text` attribute.

If I were to guess what's going on, you have another variable named `humidity` in your code somewhere that's a `UILabel` that you are accidentally mismatching. I'm assuming it's a `UILabel` because `text` is a member of the class.

You should have something like this instead of two humidity variables:

`let humidityLabel: UILabel = ...`

`let humidityValue: Double = ...`

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you! I named both the label and a variable in my code representing the humidity both "humidity"

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect `humidity.text` to be?
It's a `Double` so it won't have such a thing.
If you send some context for the `document` it will make sense.